# Xcode6 is breaking my code. Is there a fix or should I re-install it?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, osx-mavericks, uninstallation

I am developing an iPhone app. Since I upgraded from Xcode 5 to Xcode6, it's been hell. Xcode 6 would crash for no reason at all, and each crash would leave my code in some inconsistent state: where some of my pre-crash work is saved and some others aren't. After many of these crashes, I updated to `6.1`. Now `6.1` does not crash but it does something worse: whenever I change one thing, anything, in a xib file or in storyboard, something else, completely unrelated, is automatically changed. It's like Xcode has an imbecile mind of its own. If I add a UIButton, some UIView somewhere else, could be in another UIViewController, will resize, or disappear, or change state in Attributes Inspector, or lose an IBAction connection. So yes it's a wild ride. The reason I needed Xcode 6 is so that I could develop for iOS-8. Anyway, now I am ready to uninstall Xcode entirely and then try re-installing. But I don't want to break my entire computer. So, someone with knowledge, please tell me, are there any dangers to uninstalling Xcode?

Comment: Why would reinstalling Xcode hurt anything? It's just an app in your /Applications folder.

Comment: I hear a lot of funny business about Xcode6 and `6.1`. So maybe Apple is working around the clock to fix them. As for uninstalling, I don't know much about dangers. Supposedly the process is easy now a days (http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/). But I am guessing you don't just want an article. You want advice from someone with a lot of experience. In any case, good luck.

Comment: You might want to backup your drive and run a full disk check. While Xcode 6.x certainly has problems, your issues sound a bit lower-level. I prefer to download Xcode from the developer page rather than the app store and then you can have multiple versions installed at the same time.

Comment: @EricS I didn't know there was a difference. This is very useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's definitely not dangerous.

You should be able to remove any additional installed program from your Mac by simply moving it to the trash without breaking your Mac. Since Xcode 4 Xcode can be counted as a standard self contained Mac app that can simply be (re)moved from/to your Mac.

Even the commad line tools should stay installed.

*(Did you tried deleting DerivedData? That solves nearly every problem you can get with Xcode)*

Comment: what is `derived date`? I am willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: @KatedralPillon That is a directory normally located at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` where Xcode stores (pre)builds, caches, indexes, symbols files, etc. Many problems can be resolved by deleting the entire directory. Deleting this directory should not hurt any project.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and keep working to see if all is well. In the mean time, +1. Thanks for your advice.